# The simplest NIO-server example

Tags: java, nio

I'm trying to run the simplest NIO-server which just accepts connections.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    Selector selector = Selector.open();
    ServerSocketChannel serverChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
    serverChannel.configureBlocking(false);
    serverChannel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 1456));
    serverChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
    while (true) {
        try {
            selector.select();
            Iterator<SelectionKey> keys = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                SelectionKey key = keys.next();
                if (key.isAcceptable())
                    accept(key, selector);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("I/O exception occurred");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private static void accept(SelectionKey key, Selector selector) throws IOException{
    ServerSocketChannel serverChannel = (ServerSocketChannel) key.channel();
    SocketChannel channel = serverChannel.accept();
    channel.configureBlocking(false);         //<------- NPE Here
    channel.setOption(StandardSocketOptions.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
    channel.setOption(StandardSocketOptions.TCP_NODELAY, true);
    channel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
}
```

And the simplest I/O client:

```
 public static void main(String[] ars) throws IOException{
        Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 1456);
        OutputStream ous = s.getOutputStream();
        InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
        while (true) {
            ous.write(new byte[]{1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 7, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8});
            is.read();
        }
    }
```

When I run both this processes I get a bunch of `NullPointterExceeption`s.

When the client connects for the first time, it's okay. We retrieve the key, get the channel and accept the incoming connection.

But the problem is for some unclear to me reason I keep retrieving the key  that is acceptable and try to accept more. The `SocketChannel channel = serverChannel.accept();` is null and I get `NPE`.

But why am I always notified with the key that is accepted? What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove each `SelectionKey` from the selected set after you process it. Otherwise you will get the same event again, even though it isn't really ready: so for example `accept()` will return null.

You need to look at a tutorial. No good just making it up. See the Oracle NIO tutorial.

Comment: Is this true for read operation as well? I mean when I read something from a channel... Do I need to remove it from the selected set? Or just cancel it?

Comment: It is true for all operations, as any tutorial will tell you. There is rarely any need to cancel a `SelectionKey`.